# How can I print a comma separated list on 1 line with the last number ending without a comma/space/new line using a FOR loop?

Tags: java, arrays, jgrasp

```
for (i = 0; i < hourlyTemp.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i] + ", ");
     
}
```

this would give me the output that I want but with a comma the end. How can I do this without the comma at the end? is it even possible with a for-loop?

Comment: You have to write a if-statement. If "is not last element" write comma else not.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy.

```
for(int i = 0; i < hourlyTemp.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i]);
    if(i == hourlyTemp.length -1) break;
    System.out.print(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add an `if` statement for printing comma:

```
for (i = 0; i < hourlyTemp.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i]); 
    if(i != (hourlyTemp.length - 1)){
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want if condition inside a loop to avoid condition checking in case of larger array, you can use code below:

```
for (i = 0; i < hourlyTemp.length - 1; i++)
  {
    System.out.print (hourlyTemp[i] + ", ");
  }

System.out.print (hourlyTemp[hourlyTemp.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that suppressing a leading comma, instead of a trailing comma, is easier, since we don't have to use `length` to do so:

```java
for (i = 0; i < hourlyTemp.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0)
        System.out.print(", ");
    System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i]);
}
```

With a for-each loop, you'd need a flag:

```java
boolean first = true;
for (double temp : hourlyTemp) {
    if (first)
        first = false;
    else
        System.out.print(", ");
    System.out.print(temp);
}
```

You can also build a `String` with the entire line. That would perform better, since `print()` has some overhead:

```java
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (double temp : hourlyTemp)
    buf.append(", ").append(temp);
if (buf.length() != 0)
    System.out.print(buf.substring(2));
```

Using the [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) added in Java 8 is even easier:

```java
StringJoiner buf = new StringJoiner(", ");
for (double temp : hourlyTemp)
    buf.add(String.valueOf(temp));
System.out.print(buf.toString());
```